# Office JS - Edit txt file before attaching

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I would like to attach a txt file to an email and I want to be able to dynamically control the content of the txt file before attaching it. I am wanting to do this in an outlook add-in so am using office js. I have seen [this doco here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview#addfileattachmentasync-uri--attachmentname--callback-).

The `addFileAttachmentAsync` method only accepts a uri so wasn't sure if I could use this for my purposes unless I store the basic empty file somewhere and can somehow manipulate that file before attaching it.

I have seen also that there is a `addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async` method, which seems more useful but it needs api requirement set 1.8 which I think will preclude a lot of my users from being eligible to use it.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachment APIs you mentioned (`addFileAttachmentAsync` and `addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async`) do not modify the content of the attachment. To achieve your scenario, you would have to create a text file and use one of the attachment APIs to attach it.

Currently, the feature to modify an attachment from an Outlook add-in is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Is it not possible to:

-Read a file template in to memory.
-Add content to the file in memory.
-Convert to base64 
-Use addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async to add as attachment

Comment: Yes, addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async will work for attaching an existing file.